# Any difference between "I need to go home" and "I need going home"?

Tags: word-usage

I need to go home - I need going home

I heard both but don't know if "need going" is correct and if there is any difference?

Answer (score 1):

When *need* is followed by an *-ing* verb, the latter is usually interpreted as a passive. So *needs washing* means *needs to be washed*.

The form is not usually available for an intransitive verb such as *go*.